# Oracle Query that fetches one row per each _id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like :

```
ID  | Val |  Kind
----------------------
 1  |  a  |   2
 2  |  b  |   1
 3  |  c  |   4
 3  |  c  |   33
```

and I need to fetch one row per each id in Oracle SQL.
any ideas?

Comment: Your data has only one row per `id`, so the question is unclear.

Comment: Maybe the OP intended to ask for one record per kind, based on some logic (also not given).

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, i updated the data now .

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language. Do you really mean "fetch" "with PLSQL" or do you simply need an Oracle SQL `select` statement?

Comment: I updated the question, Thanks .

Comment: So, of the two _rows_ (not records) for id=3, which one do you want?  Or more generally, if you have more than one row for a given id, what is the logic for determining which one you want?  And don't say "the first one".  Rows in a relational table are like balls in a basket. There is no 'first'.  To determine 'first' _you_ have to specify some ordering criteria.

Comment: @EdStevens i want any row randomly, one sample per each _id

Comment: @BasheerRaad - I've often seen people say "any random row", but I've never understood the point of getting any random row.  If you don't care what you get, why get anything at all?

Comment: @EdStevens from my side, whenever a customer makes an activity a row will get generated, so sometimes i need to prove that those customers made an activity on a certain date and it does not matter how many activities . I can do that by grouping I know, but its better to fetch ( select *) one sample contains the whole fields per each customer. Knowing that the table that I'm dealing with contains around 100 fields . Hope you got my point .

Comment: @BasheerRaad - congratulations! That's the first actual use case for 'any random row" (thought not totally random!) I've ever heard.  Even with that, I'd think it would be better to go ahead and get all of them, just in case the customer starts asking more questions ....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows.  For an arbitrary row:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

As I point out in a comment, though, this is unnecessary based on the data in your question.  The `id`s are already unique.